# Configuration for Quarkus and Keycloak on Docker

Tags: docker, keycloak, quarkus

I have the following setup:

- Keycloak running in docker, public interface mapped to 127.0.0.1:8180, internal keycloak-n:8080
- Quarkus running in docker, public interface mapped to 127.0.0.1:8080
- Both run in the same docker network and can communicate
- An external AutzClient (not in docker) that uses the token communicate with quarkus

Everything works if client and quarkus are outside of Docker and communicate with keycloak via the same interface. As soon as quarkus is in docker, I can't get it to work.

I've tried many changes so far. On keycloak I set the frontendUrl with `/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=hostname/provider=default:write-attribute(name=properties.frontendUrl="http://127.0.0.1:8180/auth"`

My current quarkus config (oidc part) looks like:

```
# OIDC Configuration
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://keycloak-n:8080/auth/realms/quarkus
quarkus.oidc.client-id=backend-service
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=85174256-b231-4385-9fa9-257dd0d27bf0
quarkus.oidc.token.lifespan-grace=20
quarkus.oidc.introspection-path=.well-known/openid-configuration
quarkus.oidc.jwks-path=.well-known/jwks.json
quarkus.oidc.token.issuer=http://127.0.0.1:8180/auth/realms/quarkus
# Enable Policy Enforcement
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true
```

If I remove the token issuer, I get from vertx a issuer validation failed. With the current configuration the initial auth works, but than I get a Connection refused (Connection refused) from PolicyEnforcer, because it tries to communicate with 127.0.0.1. Stacktrace is:

```
2020-08-03 05:43:27,933 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.tsc.ConnPoolByRoute] (executor-thread-1) Releasing connection [{}->http://keycloak-n:8080][null]
2020-08-03 05:43:27,933 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.tsc.ConnPoolByRoute] (executor-thread-1) Pooling connection [{}->http://keycloak-n:8080][null]; keep alive indefinitely
2020-08-03 05:43:27,933 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.tsc.ConnPoolByRoute] (executor-thread-1) Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
2020-08-03 05:43:27,944 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.tsc.ThreadSafeClientConnManager] (executor-thread-1) Get connection: {}->http://127.0.0.1:8180, timeout = 0
2020-08-03 05:43:27,944 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.tsc.ConnPoolByRoute] (executor-thread-1) [{}->http://127.0.0.1:8180] total kept alive: 1, total issued: 0, total allocated: 1 out of 20
2020-08-03 05:43:27,944 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.tsc.ConnPoolByRoute] (executor-thread-1) No free connections [{}->http://127.0.0.1:8180][null]
2020-08-03 05:43:27,944 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.tsc.ConnPoolByRoute] (executor-thread-1) Available capacity: 20 out of 20 [{}->http://127.0.0.1:8180][null]
2020-08-03 05:43:27,944 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.tsc.ConnPoolByRoute] (executor-thread-1) Creating new connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:8180]
2020-08-03 05:43:27,944 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.DefaultClientConnectionOperator] (executor-thread-1) Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8180
2020-08-03 05:43:27,945 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.DefaultClientConnection] (executor-thread-1) Connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection@6ba49b73 closed
2020-08-03 05:43:27,946 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.DefaultClientConnection] (executor-thread-1) Connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection@6ba49b73 shut down
2020-08-03 05:43:27,946 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.tsc.ThreadSafeClientConnManager] (executor-thread-1) Released connection is not reusable.
2020-08-03 05:43:27,946 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.tsc.ConnPoolByRoute] (executor-thread-1) Releasing connection [{}->http://127.0.0.1:8180][null]
2020-08-03 05:43:27,946 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.DefaultClientConnection] (executor-thread-1) Connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection@6ba49b73 closed
2020-08-03 05:43:27,946 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.tsc.ConnPoolByRoute] (executor-thread-1) Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
2020-08-03 05:43:27,947 ERROR [org.key.ada.aut.PolicyEnforcer] (executor-thread-1) Could not lazy load resource with path [/hello/find/1] from server: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find resource
        at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.Throwables.retryAndWrapExceptionIfNecessary(Throwables.java:91)
        at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource.find(ProtectedResource.java:232)
        at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource.findByMatchingUri(ProtectedResource.java:291)
        at org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.PolicyEnforcer$PathConfigMatcher.matches(PolicyEnforcer.java:268)
        at org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.AbstractPolicyEnforcer.getPathConfig(AbstractPolicyEnforcer.java:351)
        at org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.AbstractPolicyEnforcer.authorize(AbstractPolicyEnforcer.java:72)
        at io.quarkus.keycloak.pep.runtime.KeycloakPolicyEnforcerAuthorizer.apply(KeycloakPolicyEnforcerAuthorizer.java:45)
        at io.quarkus.keycloak.pep.runtime.KeycloakPolicyEnforcerAuthorizer.apply(KeycloakPolicyEnforcerAuthorizer.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpAuthorizer$1$1$1.run(HttpAuthorizer.java:68)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error executing http method [GET]. Response : null
        at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethod.execute(HttpMethod.java:106)
        at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethodResponse$3.execute(HttpMethodResponse.java:68)
        at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource$5.call(ProtectedResource.java:226)
        at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource$5.call(ProtectedResource.java:222)
        at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource.find(ProtectedResource.java:230)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethod.execute(HttpMethod.java:84)
        ... 19 more

2020-08-03 05:43:27,951 DEBUG [org.key.ada.aut.AbstractPolicyEnforcer] (executor-thread-1) Checking permissions for path [http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello/find/1] with config [null].
2020-08-03 05:43:27,951 DEBUG [org.key.ada.aut.AbstractPolicyEnforcer] (executor-thread-1) Could not find a configuration for path [/hello/find/1]
```

Is there any real example on how to configure such a scenario? I already tried to set the frontendUrl to the internal address, that actually works for the runtime, but the web frontend is no longer accessible.

**UPDATE:**

From front end code (abbreviated):

```
        java.io.InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("META-INF/keycloak.json");
        auth=AuthzClient.create(stream);
        response = auth.obtainAccessToken(user, password);
        final String accessToken = response.getToken();
...
        requestContext.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX + accessToken);
...
```

and config in keycloak.json is

```
{
  "realm": "quarkus",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8180/auth/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "backend-service",
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "85174256-b231-4385-9fa9-257dd0d27bf0"
  },
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "policy-enforcer": {}
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Dear,
containers inside docker cannot communicate with 127.0.0.1 directly, did you try replacing property quarkus.oidc.token.issuer value with : http://keycloak-n:8080/auth/realms/quarkus ?

Comment: Yes, in that case I get on quarkus log only: ```2020-08-03 07:22:46,948 DEBUG [io.net.han.cod.com.ZlibCodecFactory] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-12) -Dio.netty.noJdkZlibDecoder: false
2020-08-03 07:22:46,949 DEBUG [io.net.han.cod.com.ZlibCodecFactory] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-12) -Dio.netty.noJdkZlibEncoder: false``` And on client a 403 (Forbidden) Exception

Comment: Can you share some samples of how do you generate/verify tokens from front-end ?

Comment: Ok, I suggest to switch localhost in keycloak.json and 127.0.0.1 in your application properties to (docker host ip), you can get it using ifconfig or ipconfig command.

Comment: Hi, feel kind a stupid now. The issue was solved by changing the frontenUrl in keycloak by to e.g. http://172.20.48.1:8180/auth (the docker network interface on my PC). See update in issue

Comment: This is what I meant by using (docker host ip) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the following setup works for me:

```
frontendUrl: external-docker-ip --> NOT localhost!
set in jboss cli by e.g.:
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=hostname/provider=default:write-attribute(name=properties.frontendUrl,value="http://172.20.48.1:8180/auth")

##quarkus config
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://internal_keycloak_docker_IP:8080/auth/realms/quarkus
quarkus.oidc.token.issuer=http://external-docker-ip:8180/auth/realms/quarkus

##client json file
  "auth-server-url": "http://external-docker-ip:8180/auth/"
```